# Как нажать на текст и открыть popup-окно

Tags: java, android

у меня в коде есть массив со списком  вот такой:

```
      public final static String[] INFO_KEYS = new String[] {"hello","my","world"};
```

массив создан динамический,в *JSON* прописал имена и в *String.xml* добавил их,затем вот так я получил список:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_details);
    AppLogic.getInstance().setupActionBar(this, true); // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
```

1. hello
2. my
3. world

У меня вопрос: как мне сделать так чтобы я мог нажать на текст, например на "hello", чтобы после нажатия открылось popup-окно, где я могу написать какой либо текст?

Comment: в чем именно проблема? Как обработать нажатие? Как показать Popup? как выставить текст в popup?

Comment: да проблема во всем этом

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
tvHello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu popup = new android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 100, 1, "Пункт1");
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 200, 2, "Пункт2");
        popup.show();
    }
});
```